# loop all files in a folder (VBA) - Run time error 52

Tags: excel, vba, loops, runtime-error

```
Option Explicit

Sub AllWorkbooks()
    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .Title = "Please select a folder"
    .Show
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "You did not select a folder"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    MyFolder = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

MyFile = Dir(MyFolder)
Do While MyFile <> ""
    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=MyFolder & MyFile)
    Sheets(2).Range("A1").Value = "hi!"
    wbk.Close savechanges:=True
    MyFile = Dir
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    
End Sub
```

I copy the code from this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J0PeXcAVaUM&t=169s.
When I tried to run this code, it shows "run-time error 52: Bad file name or number"
It seems that "MyFile = Dir(MyFolder)" has a problem.
How can I solve this? Thank you so much!

Comment: try `msoFileDialogFolderPicker` instead of `msoFileDialogFilePicker`

Comment: It works! Thanks!